# Objects UI in materializecss

Tags: css, user-interface, material-design, materialize

I want to change the layout of the datepicker in materializecss. One buton is labeled "CLOSE", and I want to use "DONE". (http://materializecss.com/forms.html)

Is any way to accomplish this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

In materialize.min.js look up references to the JavaScript below:

```
close:"Close"
```

Change "Close" to "Done".